# Change representation of JSON object to explicit key/value format

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "temperature": "22.2",
    "power": "6",
    "current": "156"
}
```

and I need to convert it to this explicit structure:

```
{
    "key": "temperature",
    "value": "22.2"
},
{
    "key": "power",
    "value": "6"
},
{
    "key": "current",
    "value": "156"
}
```

Is there an elegant, simple and quick way to do this?

Best, thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newStructure = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
    return {'key':key, 'value':obj[key]}
})
```

Example

```js
var obj = {
    "temperature": "22.2",
    "power": "6",
    "current": "156"
}

var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){return {'key':key,'value':obj[key]}})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Create demo to see live result.

Comment: If you use arrow notation, you can just do `Object.keys(obj).map(key=>({key,value:obj[key]}))` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bm1hs5v5/)

Comment: @4castle true, I usually avoid using arrows unless the question has them/its tagged with new ecamscript though. Feel free to add to my answer or make your own though!

Comment: I'll just leave it as a comment. I should note that [arrow functions aren't supported in IE or Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions).

Answer (score 2):

```js
Object.hashToKeyValuePairs = function (hash) {
  var ret = []; 
  for (var i in hash) 
    ret.push({ key: i, value: hash[i]}); 
  return ret; 
};

// example
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
    Object.hashToKeyValuePairs({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
);
```